# Adding 2 days and comparing

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I've written some code to check if 2 days have passed using 2 dates, but it does not seem to work.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

$_connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "theater") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM Reservering";
$result = mysqli_query($_connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res = strtotime($row['ReserveringsDatum']);
    echo date('d-m-y', $res);
}

mysqli_close($_connection);
?>
```

$row['ReserveringsDatum'] is a date which looks like this: "07-01-14" (example).

For some reason the `echo date('d-m-y', $res);` shows me "14-01-07", which is just the day and year being reversed.

**Edit:**
For those wondering how it ended up, here is the working code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

$_connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "theater") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(ReserveringsDatum)) 'age' FROM Reservering WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), ReserveringsDatum) > 2 ";
$result = mysqli_query($_connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['Betaalt'] == 'nee') {
        $query2 = "DELETE FROM Reservering WHERE `ReserveringID` = '".$row['ReserveringID']."'";
        mysqli_query($_connection, $query2);
    }
}

mysqli_close($_connection);


?>
```

Comment: Which value has got $res and $limit? Have you done a var_dump?

Comment: `$limit` will always be more than `$res` - It's defined as `$res+172800`. Are you sure you don't mean to check whether it's more than 2 days prior to the **real** date/time?

Comment: why don't you put  the logic in your sql statement? Just fetch those records that pass the 'deadline'.

Comment: @Rogier I understand your proposition, but I'm not that good with calculations using sql.

Comment: so is it working now?

Comment: @rccoros No, for some reason it says that 2 days have passed, even though the current date is 07-01-14 and the limit date is set to 09-01-14. I think there might be something wrong with my if statement.

Comment: I'm quite loss actually with what you wanted.
Do you want to check if the ReserveringsID is already two days old now or you just want to get the two days plus the date of ReserveringsID?

Comment: @rccoros I need to check if it has been over 2 days since the row has been created in the database. So I need to check if the current date is higher than the limit date (which is the creation date + 2 days).

Comment: Then you can use my suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20967856/2936759

You should use time() to get the current time and that's the one you need to compare with the limit.

Comment: @user1433479 what database you use? i think its easier to do it (and more appropriate) with SQL.  Here on SO we can help you with the SQL as-well ;-)

Comment: @user1433479 see my answer. Dutch? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, i would make the selection within SQL. There is not need selecting all the rows and filter them in PHP. Its something better done in SQL.

Simple Example:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), ReserveringsDatum) 'age' FROM Reservering WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), ReserveringsDatum) > 2
```

Make sure `reserveringsdatum` is a DATE, if its a TIMESTAMP you need to convert it to DATE.

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(ReserveringsDatum)) 'age' FROM Reservering WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), ReserveringsDatum) > 2
```

Comment: I have it set as a VARCHAR. When I change it to date or timestamp it gives me "2007-01-14" and "2007-01-14 00:00:00" respectively. I'm not sure why it is reading the 07 as the year.

Comment: I've changed the field to DATE and the way the info is being posted to the database, causing it to appear as "2014-01-07". Using this query, does it only return the rows which are over 2 days old?

Comment: I've tested this and I think it's working. I've made 7 rows, from 1 to 7 (2014-01-1 to 2014-01-07) and only those from 1 to 4 show up :D.

Comment: @user1433479 thats better. Yes MySQL stores a date as YYYY-MM-DD. Anyway, its much better to use appropriate column types. For the future you can do many more things with date calculation (like BETWEEN, WEEK, YEAR, etc.). Also storing in UTC is a better way (off topic) but like that you can easily use timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$res = strtotime($row['ReserveringsID']);
$limit = strtotime($row['ReserveringsID']) + strtotime("+2 day", $res);
var_dump($res); var_dump($limit);
if($limit > $res) {
    echo "2 days have passed";
} else {
    echo "2 days have not yet passed";
}
```

Comment: How is that different?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix you're condition.

If you want to check if $res is more than two days you have to compare limit to the current time, instead of $res.

```
$res = strtotime($row['ReserveringsID']);
$limit = strtotime('+2 days', $res);

if($limit < time()) {
    echo "2 days have passed";
} else {
    echo "2 days have not yet passed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
$limit = strtotime($row['ReserveringsID']) + $2days;
```

You need to add 2 days like this one

```
$res = strtotime($row['ReserveringsID']);
$limit = strtotime('+2 days', $res);
```

Working demo of adding 2 days to a date
https://eval.in/86632

[How do I add 24 hours to a unix timestamp in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515047/how-do-i-add-24-hours-to-a-unix-timestamp-in-php)

[Adding days to a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397577/adding-days-to-a-timestamp)

Comment: When I use your method to add 2 days it gives me 16-01-14 (instead of the expected 09-1-14). Even weirder is that it says that 2 days have passed, even though the current date is nowhere near 16-01-14

Comment: I don't know. When I get the value from the database it says it's 14-01-07, like it's turning the year and day around, and instead adding 2 years.

Comment: Better explained: I get it from the database as "07-01-14", put a strtotime over it and when I var_dump it again with date("d-m-y", $res) it shows up as 14-01-07

Comment: 5.5.3. When I used your code snippet it again gave me 14-01-07 as a result. I'll update my post to contain the entire document, maybe that will help.